# VBA: How to know if chart is in separate sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I access the format of the underlying data of a series in VBA? Something like this:

```
If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).UnderlyingXValues.NumberFormat = "m/d/yy" Then
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mmm yyyy"
Else If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).UnderlyingXValues.NumberFormat = "0" Then
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0"
End If
```

Is there something that works like UnderlyingXValues in the example above?

Comment: Are you trying to access the format? Or are you trying to determine if the `UnderlyingXValues` are on a different sheet than the `ActiveChart`?

Comment: You can parse the `.Formula` of the `SeriesCollection`.

Comment: If your series have data labels, you can refer to the series' `DataLabels` collection and access the `NumberFormat` property of each value in that collection. Note that the number formats are allowed to vary between points in a series. Alternatively, you can parse the Series `Formula` property to get the specific range address for the XValues, and refer the same way. Again, number formats may vary within a range.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the `.Formula` of the `SeriesCollection`, like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim seriesFormula As String
    seriesFormula = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula

    Dim seriesAddress As String
    seriesAddress = Split(seriesFormula, ",")(2)

    Dim seriesRng As Range
    Set seriesRng = Range(seriesAddress)

    Select Case seriesRng.NumberFormat
        Case "m/d/yy"
            ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mmm yyyy"
        Case "0"
            ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0"
    End Select
End Sub
```

As already pointed out, the number formatting of the source range must be consistent for this to work.

Comment: One way to avoid an error if varying number formats: assume the *first* number format is the desired one: `Select Case seriesRng.Cells(1).NumberFormat`. If that's not a safe assumption for the OP (though it probably is), then s/he would need to implement some additional logic. Nice answer :)

Comment: @DavidZemens yeah I thought about proposing that as well.