# Get datalabel caption source cell address

Tags: excel, vba

I'm at a loss and not sure if there is a way to do this.

I have a chart with data labels. The data label captions are linked to cell values.  For each data label, I need to get the address of the cell that is the source for the caption.

The data label sources were set manually using the format data labels property manager.

[image]

Unfortunately, everything I've tried just returns the text value of the caption - nothing will give me the cell address that I need.

For example, when I run the following, I get the same value for all these lines - it just prints the text from the caption.

I can get the range of cells for the whole series ($H$9:$H$22) using `dl.parent.parent.formula`, but what I need is the specific cell address for each data label (i.e. first label: $H$9, second label: $H$10, etc.)

```
Private Sub test()
Dim C As Chart
Dim w As Worksheet
Set w = Sheet2
Set C = Sheet2.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

Dim dl As DataLabel
    For Each dl In C.FullSeriesCollection(2).DataLabels
        Debug.Print dl.Text
        Debug.Print dl.Caption
        Debug.Print dl.Formula
        Debug.Print dl.FormulaLocal
        Debug.Print dl.FormulaR1C1
        Debug.Print dl.FormulaR1C1Local
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the captions to : =CELL("address";A1)?

Comment: Hey Daghan, I have not. I might be missing something, but wouldn't that SET the caption source?  I don't want to change the source of the caption - I just want to GET the address of the current source. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: What do you want to do with each cell address? You should be able to loop through the range of cells from the formula of the series. I'm not sure if there's an easier way.

Comment: It's a bar graph. I want to set the color of the bar equal to the color of the source cell.  I might try that approach. I could add a counter to my for/each loop and select the cell from the source range using the counter to index...

Comment: Or you could loop the source range, but yeah pretty much the same idea. I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58940865/9245853) a question that involves getting the source range easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working solution following BigBen's suggestion.  If anyone wants to post a better/cleaner approach I'd be happy to mark as answer.

```
Sub ChartConditions()
Dim C As Chart
Dim W As Worksheet
Dim S As Series
Set W = Sheet2
Set C = Sheet2.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
Set S = C.FullSeriesCollection(2)

Dim sForm As String
Dim sAdd As String
Dim sRange As Range

sForm = S.Formula
sAdd = Split(sForm, ",")(2)
Set sRange = Range(sAdd)

Dim dlRange As Range
Set dlRange = Intersect(Range("H1").EntireColumn, sRange.EntireRow)

Dim i As Long
i = 0

Dim dl As DataLabel
    For Each dl In S.DataLabels
        i = i + 1
        Dim r As Long, b As Long, g As Long
        getRGB3 dlRange(i, 1), r, b, g
        dl.Parent.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(r, g, b)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub getRGB3(rcell As Range, r As Long, b As Long, g As Long)
    Dim C As Long

    C = rcell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    r = C Mod 256
    g = C \ 256 Mod 256
    b = C \ 65536 Mod 256

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you do the `intersect` with the column H? Also, be carefull, the code will fail if your sheet is not the `ActiveSheet` as the unqualified  `Range` will refer to `ActiveSheet`

Comment: @FunThomas - actually the `Range` is passed an address including the sheet name. In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58940865/9245853) I already mentioned, an unqualified `Range` call works even though in that setup, the data was already on a different sheet. It's an edge case where an unqualified `Range` call actually works.

Comment: @funthomas - the data range for the series is not the same as the range which supplies the captions. The data is in column S and the caption text is in column H. The intersect gets me the range with the captions, which is color coded.